# Returning data from $.when with multiple $.getJSON calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

In the following code, I am retrieving data using `$.getJSON` (returned form the repository) and `$.when` as the last call is dependent on data from the first:

```
var getData =

    function () {

        var data = { userData: null, userTitles: null, userPage: null };

        $.when(repository.getUserDetails().done(f1)),
                    repository.getUserPolicyTitles().done(f2)
            .then(repository.getUserPage().done(f3));


        function f1(userData) { data.userData = userData; console.log(data.userData) };
        function f2(userTitles) { data.userTitles = userTitles; console.log(data.userTitles) };
        function f3(userPage) { data.userPage = userPage; console.log(data.userPage) };

        return data;
    }

   return {
       getData: getData
   };
```

Most of this works fine.  However, I would like to return the data back to a calling module but it returns before the data is ready as I suppose you would expect.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Davy

Comment: The `$.when()` expression doesn't make sense. It has one argument, and is followed by a `,`. Are you sure the brackets `()` close in the right place?

Comment: Thanks, I think  docs say you can pass multiple functions into the $.when - basically to execute them both before doing the third in the $.then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of deferred seems incorrect. This is my interpretation.

Also, you need to consider that once you start invoking asynchronous methods, you can't make a synchronous return call, which is what you're doing. Instead of returning data, you need to return a promise; then you provide the promise with a callback that will do stuff with the data

```
var getData = function () {
    var myDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var data = { userData: null, userTitles: null, userPage: null };

    $.when(repository.getUserDetails().done(f1),
           repository.getUserPolicyTitles().done(f2),
           repository.getUserPage().done(f3)).then(
        function(){ myDeferred.resolve(data); },
        function(){ myDeferred.reject.apply(myDeferred, arguments); });

    //... f1, f2, f3

    return myDeferred.promise();
}

return {
    getData: getData
};
```

Then, when you want to actually use the data, you do

```
your_library.getData().then(function(data){
        // magic goes here
    }, function(errors_of_some_sort) {
        // error handling magic goes here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. I had tried something similar but couldn't put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

When using $.when, you can only get the data after all your AJAX calls have returned.  So for example:

```
$.when($.getJSON('somewhere'), $.getJSON('somewhere2'))
.done(function(r1, r2){
    //set your data object with the responses from the server here
});
```

So the short answer is you can't "return" the data you retrieved from the server, but you can assign a callback to use the data (or set to some entity of your module) when the data is ready.